# Tracking state of a chain of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm currently trying to track the progress of a chain of native es6 promises, and am wondering what the 'correct' way to go about this is.
I've simplified the actual code to thie following example, which is a basic set of chained promises (in reality, the promise chain is longer, and the session status value changes in more places depending on progress through the chain):

```
let sessions = {}

const asyncFunc = () => {
  // Get a new id for state tracking
  let session_id = getID()
  sessions.session_id = 'PENDING'
  // Fetch the first url
  let result = api.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      // Return the 'url' property of the fetched data
      return res.url
    })
    .then (url => {
      // Fetch this second url
      let data = api.get(url)
      sessions.session_id = 'SUCCESS'
      // Return the whole data object
      return data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("ERR", err)
      sessions.session_id = 'ERROR'
    })
  return result
}

asyncFunc()
  .then(res => {
    console.log("URL", url)
  })
```

This code tracks the state of the functions and stores them to the global `sessions` object - but the `session_id` isn't being passed back for inspection of status while the function is 'in-flight'.

One option I'm considering is adding the `session_id` as a property of the promise when it is returned, so this can be inspected - however I'm not sure if adding a property to a promise is a risky/hacky thing to do?  Something like (simplified from above):

```
const asyncFunc = () => {
  // Get a new id for state tracking
  let session_id = getID()
  sessions.session_id = 'PENDING'
  // Fetch the first url
  let result = api.get(url)
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)

  // Add the session_id to the promise
  result.session_id = session_id
  return result
}

let func = asyncFunc()
let status =sessions[func.session_id]
func.then(...)
```

Any thoughts on the validity of this approach? I can see that I would probably also need to push the session id into the final return value as well, (so that the property exists in both the promise, and the resulting value of the resolved/rejected promise).

Alternatively, any other ways of handling this?

The obvious one is to make the function always return an array of arguments (promise and session_id) but I'd prefer to avoid having to always do e.g.:

```
let func = asyncFunc()
let status =sessions[func[1]]
func[0].then(...)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the "tracking value"? If you want to be notified when it changes, a property won't help you. Call a callback instead.

Comment: you can use await for avoid so many promise chaining

Comment: Sorry - that was a spurious `return` there - fixed now. The session_id is the key of the specific session in the global `sessions` object (the value is then used as  a 'watched' property in a reactive framework).

Comment: @warl0ck Yes I could use `await` here, but I don't see how that would affect the session tracking?

Comment: @match And that reactive framework repeatedly polls the property? Doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Do you want to track progress of a series of things, or do you just want to track the state of the final promise?

Comment: Reactive frameworks wrap 'global state' with change events and callbacks - e.g. react, vue or angular - however for simplicity in this example I'm just using a simple `sessions` object. (And yes, SUCCESS should be in the `then` - fixed the example.

Comment: In reality the chain is more complex and status can be updated to several different values depending on the results of each promise in the chain.

Comment: I would then recommend to simply pass the state object as an argument to `asyncFunc` and have it updated whenever you want. Extracting the `status` in a variable makes no sense, and I don't see why the `asyncFunc` would need to return the tracking object.

Comment: There are many separate calls of `asyncFunc` each of which is updating it's own session status in the `sessions` object, using the generated `session_id`. `asyncFunc` needs to return this id which can then be looked up in `sessions`.